# How to sequence a sliding window of with step 2 on character vector in r

Tags: r, vector, character, sequence

I know how to code for sequencing a sliding window of 3 with step 1 in a character vector, but would step 2 require a `seq` function?

So for step 1:

```
v <- c("ace", "king", "queen", "jack", "joker")

for(i in 1:3) {
    print(paste(v[i], v[i + 1], v[i + 2]))
}
## ace king queen
## king queen jack
## queen jack joker
```

How would I modify this to have a step of 2 i.e. get output of:

```
## ace king queen
## queen jack joker
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `shift` from `data.table` with `type='lead'` and 'n' specified as `vector` of sequence from 0 to 2

```
library(data.table)
do.call(rbind, shift(vector, 0:2, type = "lead"))[,1:3]
#     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
#[1,] "ace"   "king"  "queen"
#[2,] "king"  "queen" "jack" 
#[3,] "queen" "jack"  "joker"
```

If we want the second sequence then use `n = c(0, 2)`

```
do.call(rbind, shift(vector, c(0, 2), type = "lead"))[, 1:3]
#     [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   
#[1,] "ace"   "king" "queen"
#[2,] "queen" "jack" "joker"
```

---

Or we can use `rollapply` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(vector, 3, FUN = I)[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
#     [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   
#[1,] "ace"   "king" "queen"
#[2,] "queen" "jack" "joker"
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
apply(embed(vector, 3), 1, rev)[c(TRUE, FALSE),]
#     [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   
#[1,] "ace"   "king" "queen"
#[2,] "queen" "jack" "joker"
```

#### data

```
vector <- c('ace', 'king', 'queen', 'jack', 'joker')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `by` argument in `zoo`'s `rollapply` function.

```
v <- c("ace", "king", "queen", "jack", "joker")

library(zoo)
rollapply(v, width=3, paste, by=2)
#     [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   
#[1,] "ace"   "king" "queen"
#[2,] "queen" "jack" "joker"
```